# Non-type parameter in function template

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, non-type

I've a very simple template function, but there's confusion as to how to instantiate/call the function because of the non-type parameter.
The definition of the template function is as goes:

```
template<typename Glorp, int size>
Glorp min(Glorp array[size])
{

Glorp minival = array[0];
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
if (array[i] < minival)
    minival = array[i];

return minival;
}
```

Now, in `main()` I have the following code:

```
void main()
{
const int size=5;
int array[size];
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    cin >> array[i];

int p = min(array[size]);
cout << p;
}
```

This gets me the error message:

```
Error   1   error C2783: 'Glorp min(Glorp *)' : could not deduce template argument for 'size'   c:\users\tamara\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\nuevoprojecto\nuevoprojecto\main.cpp  23  1   NuevoProjecto
```

How DO I call this function from `main()`? I can't find the answer for this, the only examples I saw were for non type parameters in template classes

Answer (score 3):

I see two major problems in you code

1) the syntax for a template function receiving an array, deducing the type and the size, is the following

```
template <typename Glorp, int size>
Glorp min (Glorp (&array)[size])
 {
   // ...........^^^^^^^^
 }
```

2) you have to call it without `[size]`

```
int p = min(array[size]); // wrong
int p = min(array);       // correct
```

because passing `array[size]` you're trying to pass a single `int` from an un-allocated memory position (correct `array` values are from `array[0]` to `array[size-1]`).

A minor problem: `main()` return a `int`, not a `void`.

Off topic suggestion: if you can use at least C++11, consider using `std::array`, instead of old C-style arrays, whenever possible.

Comment: I've tried that syntax, but I get the error:  
    Error 1 error C2234: 'array' : arrays of references are illegal  
 
Which is the reason I thought to delete the '&' symbol  

And for the call, I get the error:  
    Error 2 error C2784: 'Glorp min(Glorp *[size])' : could not deduce 
    template argument for 'Glorp *[size]' from 'int [5]'  

Which is why I put array[size], instead of just array.  

Thanks for the suggestion, I know that's more practical, this was an example in one of my books and I wanted to see how it would work (although it clearly doesn't).